# Breaking a while loop when an input function is included

Tags: python-3.x

I want to break a loop when an input is equal to negative one. i have tried using the if function in combination with my value and break

```
def while_input():
    while True:
        inp = input('use -1 to break')
        if inp == -1:
            break
```

This continues to prompt for further input even when -1 has been input.

please help!!

Comment: `input` returns a `str`, not an `int`. Compare to a string, or convert your input first.

Comment: oh wow. thank you for correcting my stupidity